# Where is this "access" property coming from on my DirectorySecurity object?

Tags: powershell, acl

I'm reading some code and I can't figure out where a certain property, access, is being retrieved from.

Here is a snippet of the code I am looking at. I've removed some of the code. This code is part of a function, hence the return statements, but the rest of the func code isn't relevant to this post.

```
if ($targetObjType -eq "DirectoryInfo") {
                $fileFolderObjs = @(Get-ChildItem $target -force -recurse -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
}
$fileFolderObjs | ForEach-Object {
            $fileFolderObj = $_
            try {
                $ACL = $fileFolderObj.GetAccessControl()
            }
            catch {
                write-host "error"
                return
            }
            if (!$ACL) {
                return
            }
            $access = $ACL | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access #ACLs. Not seeing this property as existing in DirectorySecurity class documentation. 
}
```

So I should be retrieving DirectoryInfo objects, calling GetAccessControl() on them, and getting a DirectorySecurity object back in return. The code runs properly and access property does return data, but I can't find any information in Microsoft docs for where this Access property comes from. It's not listed as a property on the DirectorySecurity object. Am I missing some object that DirectorySecurity inherits from?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `.Access` is a code property that contains a type `System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRuleCollection`. It is an extended property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell's type system, sometimes known as the Extended Type System (or ETS) works by transparently wrapping native .NET objects in a [`PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject), which in turns allow us to extend types without actually modifying the type and identity of the underlying object.

In your specific case, the `Access` property comes from a set of dynamic properties added to instances of `System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity`.

Digging into the type data exposed by `Get-TypeData`, we can even see it maps to a static method exposed by the class from which `Get-Acl` derives:

```
$objectSecurityExtendedMembers = Get-TypeData -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity|% Members
$objectSecurityExtendedMembers['Access']
```

---

Although it won't necessarily tell you from where it came, `Get-Member` would have revealed `Access` to be an ETS (and not a native .NET) property:

```
PS C:\> Get-Acl |Get-Member


   TypeName: System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity

Name                            MemberType     Definition
----                            ----------     ----------
Access                          CodeProperty   System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRuleCollection Access{get=GetAccess;}
CentralAccessPolicyId           CodeProperty   System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier CentralAccessPolicyId{get=GetCentra...
CentralAccessPolicyName         CodeProperty   System.String CentralAccessPolicyName{get=GetCentralAccessPolicyName;}
Group                           CodeProperty   System.String Group{get=GetGroup;}
Owner                           CodeProperty   System.String Owner{get=GetOwner;}
Path                            CodeProperty   System.String Path{get=GetPath;}
Sddl                            CodeProperty   System.String Sddl{get=GetSddl;}
AccessRuleFactory               Method         System.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule AccessRuleFactory(System.Security.Princ...
AddAccessRule                   Method         void
```

Notice how it says it's a `CodeProperty` and not a regular `Property`. Anything that isn't listed as `Method`, `Property` or `Event` is a PowerShell-specific member.

Comment: Hmm. I'm having a hard time piecing things together. Most likely because I'm a complete PS novice. How are you supposed to know what dynamic properites/methods an object could extend without using Get-TypeData? I feel like you couldn't. I could be looking in the wrong place but I don't see anything in the docs referencing the members that ObjectSecurity can expose.

Comment: `Get-Member` is your friend