# Where is the "Target" member of a System.IO.FileInfo documented?

Tags: .net, powershell

The PowerShell commandlet `Get-Item`, if applied on a file, returns a `System.IO.FileInfo` type:

```
PS C:\> $item = get-item c:\windows\System32\atl.dll
PS C:\> $item.GetType().FullName
System.IO.FileInfo
```

Using the tabulator on `$item`, I find that it has a member/property named `Target`:

```
PS C:\> $item.Target
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-atl_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.18362.1_none_7d7dafc1d6eadbc7\atl.dll
```

However, there is no mention of that member/property in Microsoft's documentation for
[System.IO.FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8)
and its base class [System.IO.FileSystemInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo?view=netframework-4.8).

I suspect that the value of `Target` is some kind of where a junction or symbolic or hard link points to - yet, if I apply `Target` on the target-file, I get the original file again:

```
PS C:\> (get-item $item.Target).Target
C:\Windows\System32\atl.dll
```

So, what is this `Target` member?

Comment: [It's an ETS CodeProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61062261/where-is-this-access-property-coming-from-on-my-directorysecurity-object/61062829#61062829) and it comes from `$PSHOME\typesv3.ps1xml`

Comment: Just use `Get-Member`

Comment: Ok, I understand where `Target` comes from, but it's still a mystery why there each target  points to each other's target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

- There is no documentation for ETS (Extended Type System) members such as `.Target`.
- `c:\windows\System32\atl.dll` is one of two so-called [*hard links*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) that point to the same file data (the other being `C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-atl_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.18362.1_none_7d7dafc1d6eadbc7\atl.dll`).

  - For hard links, `.Target` reports all the *other* hard links (paths that point to the same file), which is why the `.Target` property values of the two items point to the respective other path.
- Your code no longer works in PowerShell [Core], where support for reporting hard links via `.Target` was removed - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11562).

---

As Mathias R. Jessen points out, the **`.Target`** property is an [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml) property - a property added by PowerShell to extend the capabilities of a native .NET type.

There is ***no* documentation for such ETS members** (which may also include *methods*) - your **best bet is to study their *definition***, which isn't guaranteed to give you the full story or only with a nontrivial amount of effort:

In a first step, you can use the [`Get-TypeData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-typedata) cmdlet to inspect the definition of the `.Target` property (which is added to both `System.IO.FileInfo` and `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` instances):

```
# Windows PowerShell
PS> (Get-TypeData System.IO.FileInfo).Members.Target | foreach GetCodeReference

Name                       : GetTarget
DeclaringType              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InternalSymbolicLinkLinkCodeMethods
[...]
MemberType                 : Method
ReturnType                 : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]
[...]
```

(`Get-Item $PROFILE | Get-Member Target` can also be used, but lacks important information in this case: the `.Target` property is of type `CodeProperty`, i.e. a property whose value is determined by a call to a static method of a .NET type, but the output's `.Definition` property shows the method only as  `Target{get=GetTarget;}`; that is, the *full type name* is missing).

That is, a call to `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InternalSymbolicLinkLinkCodeMethods]::GetTarget()` with the `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` instance at hand is used to return that instance's `.Target` property value.

- In *Windows PowerShell*, this is the end of the line, given that its source code isn't publicly available.
- In PowerShell [Core] 6+, you can examine the source code in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/PowerShell), notably in file [`FileSystemProvider.cs`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/8869e7a4cd4c52dcaa1ebcc7c0b6a4329e710a60/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/TypeTable_Types_Ps1Xml.cs#L807) (this link is a permalink, which will become outdated over time; click on the `Branch:` dropdown list at the top of the page to switch to the current `master` branch).

The partially inferred behavior of `.Target` is discussed next.

---

#### `.Target`'s purpose and behavior:

- The `.Target` property returns a file-system *reparse point*'s (Windows) / *symlink*'s (symbolic link's; Unix) target path(s).<sup>[1]</sup>
- If the input path *isn't* a reparse point or symlink, `.Target` returns "nothing": specifically, `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` (Windows PowerShell; behaves like `$null` in most contexts) / `$null` (PowerShell [Core]).

There's an important difference in the behavior of `.Target`  between Windows PowerShell and PowerShell [Core] 6+ (as of PowerShell 7.0):

- In Windows PowerShell, `.Target` returns an *enumeration* of target paths, meaning that *multiple* paths may be returned, which only applies if the input path is one of several [*hard links*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) to the same *file* (data).

  - Specifically, a hard link's `.Target` property reports all *other* hard links that exist to that file (i.e., not including the input path).
  - This explains why, given a file with *two* hard links, their `.Target` properties point to the respective other path, as is the case with the file pointed to by hard link `C:\Windows\System32\atl.dll`, for instance.
- In PowerShell [Core], `.Target` only every returns a *single* path, because *support for hard links was removed* - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11562).

  - As an aside: Unlike Windows, Unix-like platforms have no system-level support for enumerating hard links, so finding all hard links to a given file is both cumbersome and slow.

---

<sup>[1] Apart from [hard links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link), Unix-like platforms have only [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), whereas on Windows the category of [*reparse points*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_reparse_point) comprises not only symbolic links, but also *junctions*, *volume mount points*, and, in recent Windows versions, *AppX reparse points* (app execution aliases for Microsoft Store applications).</sup>